# C++ "Count the number of collisions at each slot in the hash table"

Tags: c++, list, class, hashtable

I'm suppose to create a Dictionary as a Hash Table with Linked List to spell check a text document. I read in the file "words.txt" to create the dictionary. Also, I have to count/display the number of collisions at each slot in the hash table when I load in the dictionary "words.txt"

I'm given the source code for the HashTable Class with Linked List as followed :

hashtable.cpp (#include "listtools.cpp" since its using templates)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "listtools.h"
#include "listtools.cpp"
#include "hashtable.h"

using LinkedListSavitch::Node;
using LinkedListSavitch::search;
using LinkedListSavitch::headInsert;
using namespace std;

#define HASH_WEIGHT 31

namespace HashTableSavitch
{
   HashTable::HashTable()
   {
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
     hashArray[i] = NULL;
     //array for collisons
     collisionArray[i] = 0;
    }
   }

   HashTable::~HashTable()
   {
     for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
     {
       Node<string> *next = hashArray[i];
       while (next != NULL)
       {
         Node<string> *discard = next;
     next = next->getLink( );
     delete discard;
       }
     }
   }

   unsigned int HashTable::computeHash(string s) const
   {
    unsigned int hash = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s.length( ); i++)
    {
        hash = HASH_WEIGHT * hash + s[i];
    }
    return hash % SIZE;
   }

   bool HashTable::containsString(string target) const
   {
    int hash = this->computeHash(target);
    Node<string>* result = search(hashArray[hash], target);
    if (result == NULL)
       return false;
    else
       return true;
   }

   void HashTable::put(string s)
   {
       int count = 0;
       int hash = computeHash(s);
       if (search(hashArray[hash], s) == NULL)
       {
           // Only add the target if it's not in the list
           headInsert(hashArray[hash], s);
       }
       else
       {
               collisionArray[hash]++;
   }
   void HashTable::printArray()
   {
   int number;
   for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
       number = collisionArray[i];
       cout << "----------------\n";
       cout << "index = " << i << endl;
       cout << "Collisions = " << number << endl;
       cout << "----------------\n";
   }
   }
} // HashTableSavitch
```

my main.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include "hashtable.h"
using namespace std;
using HashTableSavitch::HashTable;

void upToLow(string & str);
void removePunct(string & str);

int main()
{
    HashTable h;
    string currWord;
    string word;
    int countMisspelled = 0;
    int countCorrect = 0;

    //Get input from words.rtf
    ifstream dictionary("words.txt");

    //File checking
    if (dictionary.fail())
    {
        cout << "File does not exist" << endl;
        cout << "Exit program" << endl;
    }

    //Create the dictionary as a hash table
    while(dictionary >> currWord)
    {
        h.put(currWord);
    }
    dictionary.close();

    //display collisions
    h.printArray();

    //Get input from gettysburg_address.txt
    ifstream input("gettysburg_address.txt");

    //File checking
    if (input.fail())
    {
        cout << "File does not exist" << endl;
        cout << "Exit program" << endl;
    }

    //Spell check gettysburg_address.txt
    cout << "Misspelled words : " << endl;
    cout << endl;

    //If a word is not in the dictionary assume misspelled
    while(input >> word)
    {
        removePunct(word);
        upToLow(word);
        if(h.containsString(word) == false)
        {
            countMisspelled++; // Increment misspelled words count
            cout << word << " ";
            if(countMisspelled % 20 == 0) // Display misspelled words 20 per line
            {
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            countCorrect++; // Increment correct words count
        }
    }
    input.close();

    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Number of misspelled words : " << countMisspelled << endl;
    cout << "Number of correct words : " << countCorrect << endl;

    return 0;
}


/*Function to convert uppercase letters to lowercase*/
void upToLow(string & str)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(str.c_str()); i++)
         if (str[i] >= 0x41 && str[i] <= 0x5A)
              str[i] = str[i] + 0x20;
}


/*Function to remove punctuation from string*/
void removePunct(string & str)
{
    str.erase(remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), static_cast<int(*)(int)>(&ispunct)),str.end());
}
```

Is there a simple way to count the number of collisions at each slot when loading in "words.txt" ? If I implement a count variable in the "put" function I can get the total number of collisions, but I'm not quite sure how to count/display the number of collisions at each slot of the hash table. Any help/tips is appreciated.

***EDIT*** :
Followed Joe's advice and now I'm wondering how I could display the number of collisions at each slot. I made a void function to do just that but it displays the number of collisions at each slot to be 0. Anyone know what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is declare an array in an appropriate place

```
int collisionArray[SIZE];
```

initialize it to 0 in `HashTable::HashTable()`

```
HashTable::HashTable()
{
 for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
 {
  hashArray[i] = NULL;
  collisionArray[i] = 0;
 }
}
```

then increment the appropriate element when a collision is found

```
void HashTable::put(string s)
{
    int count = 0;
    int hash = computeHash(s);
    if (search(hashArray[hash], s) == NULL)
    {
        // Only add the target if it's not in the list
        headInsert(hashArray[hash], s);
        collisionArray[hash]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But now I'm having troubles printing out the number of collisions at each slot. I made a void function for printing out the collisions at each slot but the collisions all turn out to be 0. Any tips?

Comment: Apologies, I was thinking duplicate not collision.  With the increment in the else block  of the put, it will only increment when the same string is seen twice.  To count the number of discrete strings that hash to the same value, put the `collisionArray[hash]++;` line in the if block.

Comment: I've edited the code to reflect that.  The `collisionArray` should end up holding the count of discrete strings at each hash location.